powershell import local polices
I'd like import some local polices editor (gpedit.msc) from my PC and output in file or in script in powershell so I prepare code:
'Import-Module PolicyFileEditor
$policy = "$env:windir\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol"
$minPasswordPolicy = Get-PolicyFileEntry -Path $policy | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq   
"MinimumPasswordLength" }
$minPasswordPolicy | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "Policy: $_.Name"
    Write-Output "Value: $_.Data"
} 
$minPasswordPolicy > C:\scripts\file.txt'

It doesn't work.
I tried output/print some local polices in powershell.

"It didn't work" .. what did it do instead ?
